# How to include reference to assembly in ASP.NET Core project

Tags: c#, .net, visual-studio-2015, asp.net-core, assembly-references

I have this line

```
string sConnectionString = ConfigurationManager.ConnectionStrings["Hangfire"].ConnectionString;
```

And it requires to include  [System.Configuration](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.configuration.configurationmanager.connectionstrings(v=vs.110).aspx)

In which place of the project I have to add reference to `System.Configuration` because I cannot find a classic place to do it under `References`?

[image]

Comment: .Net Core projects use a different configuration model that is based on `Microsoft.Extensions.Configuration` rather than `System.Configuration`. Where is your actual `HangFire` connection-string is set? In your `appsettings.json`?

Comment: @haim770 I am study this manual http://www.talkingdotnet.com/integrate-hangfire-with-asp-net-core-web-api/

Answer (score 11, accepted):

The tutorial your're following is probably using Asp.Net Core targeting the full .Net Framework (4.6) that is capable of relying on `System.Configuration` (that is not portable and not supported in CoreFX).

.Net Core projects (being cross-platform) use a different configuration model that is based on [`Microsoft.Extensions.Configuration`](https://www.nuget.org/packages/Microsoft.Extensions.Configuration/) rather than on `System.Configuration`.

Assuming your `Hangfire` connection-string is defined in your `appsettings.json`:

```
{
     "ConnectionStrings": {
         "HangFire": "yourConnectionStringHere"
     }
}
```

You can read it in your `Startup.cs`:

```
public class Startup
{
    public Startup(IHostingEnvironment env)
    {
        var builder = new ConfigurationBuilder()
            .AddJsonFile("appsettings.json", optional: true, reloadOnChange: true)

        this.Configuration = builder.Build();

        var hangFireCS = this.Configuration.GetConnectionString("HangFire");
    }
}
```

Also, you're gonna need the [`Microsoft.Extensions.Configuration.Json`](https://www.nuget.org/packages/Microsoft.Extensions.Configuration.Json/) package to use the `AddJsonFile()` extension method.

Comment: I agree with you but why the manual I am facing has presented the old approach that is not supported now in Asp.Net Core ? Does it mean that manual is incorrect?

Comment: There's nothing "incorrect" about it, per se. You can build Asp.Net Core apps that are targeting the full framework (4.6). But you won't gain all the benefits and portability of the Core framework.

Answer (score -2):

@Dimi Right Click on References folder -> Add References -> Search configuration -> check on System.Configuration -> Click on ok.

then add Namespaces on your .cs file i.e

using System.Configuration;

[image]
[image]

Comment: It says NO ITEMS FOUND

Comment: Sorry I cannot see the same windows like you. I have created ASP.NET Core Webapi project. See my updated question, please

Comment: https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/aspnet/core/fundamentals/configuration

Comment: visit above links

Comment: Sorry but it does not help to execute a simple operation to add an assembly that we did in Visual Studio during last 12 years.

Comment: @Dimi: This is ASP.NET Core/.NET Core it is completely modular and based on NuGet packages. You won't have the files lying around as with .NET Framework before. Whatever you need, you need to reference it in project.json (soon inside csproj when VS2017 comes)

Comment: @Tseng Hi! Please provide the detailed answer and I will vote it.